# I'm having trouble creating an automatic slideshow in droid

Tags: android, animation, slideshow, drawable

When I open droid I don't want any buttons I just want a sequence of images to automatically show, each for a few seconds before it's replaced with another image and once all the images are shown have it loop back to the first image. I am still new to droid development and I am obviously missing something. any help will be greatly appreciated.

my java file

```
public class Slidingpics2Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.treat);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.theanime);

    AnimationDrawable Anime = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
    Anime.start();

}

}
```

I put theanime.xml file in the drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="1000" />
</animation-list>
```

after that I mad my layout main.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/treat" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound what you need is a [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html):

> Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that
>   have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval

Comment: cool, I changed the ImageView to Viewflipper and I now see the first image when I start the app but now for some reason It does not switch to the second image

Comment: You need to set the autostart and flipinterval variables, either in xml with `android:autoStart="true"` and `android:flipInterval="interval"` or, from your java code: `flipper.setFlipInterval(milliseconds)` and `setAutoStart(true)` (or `startFlipping()`)

Comment: tried both **setAutoStart(true)** & 'startFlipping()' I still have the same problem

This is how I have it setup

    'ViewFlipper image = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.treat);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.theanime);
        image.setFlipInterval(5000);
        image.setAutoStart(true);
    }
    }'

Comment: Ah, I see. You should set the image/s on imageviews that are placed as children of the ViewFlipper, using `setImageResource()`/`android:src=""`.  I found an example for you here: http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-view-flipper-in-android.html. This uses textviews, but the general principle is the same.